# Codeigniter regex_match with Comparison

Tags: php, regex, codeigniter

I have this regex_match like -

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('oper_nic', 'NIC', 'trim|required|min_length[10]|regex_match[/^[0-9]{9}[vVxX]$/]');
```

It validate  9 number followed by one letter that is v, V, x or X.

I need to combine the above validation to an another field witch which can enter year like 1988.and validate **(88)** value in both fields at the same time.

> Ex : Value **880989898V** (According to the expression this is
>   correct)

Another field I am entering for a separate text field the value for it is - **1993**

> According to the value **1993** is wrong and **1988** should be correct

because 1st value start with 88 and other value ends with 88.

How can I write a code using CodeIgniter to achieve this.

Comment: Unless you clarify, I guess it will be impossible to help you.

Comment: what do u mean @stribizhev

Comment: No, what do *you* mean? Please clarify in the post.

Comment: Use callback function to compare values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can Write a callback function like [@tpojka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32527385/codeigniter-regex-match-with-comparison/32573021#comment52916727_32527385) suggested. Here is an example:

```
class Form extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        // load stuff
        // ...

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('oper_nic', 'NIC', 'trim|required|min_length[10]|regex_match[/^[0-9]{9}[vVxX]$/]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('year', 'Year', 'callback_year_check');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            // failure
        }
        else
        {
            // success
        }
    }

    public function year_check($str)
    {
        if (substr($str, -2) == substr($this->form_validation->set_value('oper_nic'), 0, 2)) 
        {
            return true;
        } 
        return false;
    }
}
```

And of course I have mentioned only one validation flag for simplicity, realistically you would need something like:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('year', 'Year', 'trim|required|regex_match[/^[0-9]{4}$/]|callback_year_check');
```